# How to unselect a particular document in mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose

I have access to `userId` and I want to get result without document of that particular user. How can I do this in mongoose?

```
async peopleyoumayknow(req, res) {
    const {id} = req.params
    const response = await userModel.find({}).sort({creation_date:-1}).limit(12)
    return res.send(response)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code to

```
async peopleyoumayknow(req, res){
    const {id} = req.params
    const response = await userModel.find({ _id: {"$ne": id}}).sort({creation_date:-1}).limit(12);
    return res.send(response)
  }
```